# macOS Vagrant image stuck on "boot.efi, launching..", Linux host

Tags: linux, virtualbox, macos, vagrant

This is my `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ramsey/macos-catalina"
  config.vm.define "macosx-test"
  config.vm.box_version = "1.0.0"

  ## NFS needs host-only network
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.100"
  #Ranges: 192.168.56.0/21 

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |virtualbox|
    virtualbox.name = "macosx-test"
    virtualbox.memory = 4096
    virtualbox.cpus = 2
    # Show gui, incl. some power
    virtualbox.gui = false

    # Some needed OSX configs
    virtualbox.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuid-set", "00000001", "000106e5", "00100800", "0098e3fd", "bfebfbff"]
    virtualbox.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct", "MacBookPro11,3"]
    virtualbox.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion", "1.0"]
    virtualbox.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct", "Iloveapple"]
    virtualbox.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey", "ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"]
    virtualbox.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC", "1"]

    # set resolution on OSX:
    # 0,1,2,3,4,5 :: 640x480, 800x600, 1024x768, 1280x1024, 1440x900, 1920x1200
    virtualbox.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode", "4"]
  end

end
```

When I run `vagrant up`, I get:

[image]

If I open `virtualbox` and open the `display`, I get:

[image]

**How can I get it to work ?**

---

Versions:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -E 'vagrant|virtualbox'
ii  ruby-vagrant-cloud                            3.0.5-1                                    all          Vagrant Cloud API Library
ii  vagrant                                       2.2.19+dfsg-1ubuntu1                       all          Tool for building and distributing virtualized development environments
ii  vagrant-libvirt                               0.7.0-1                                    all          Vagrant plugin that adds an Libvirt provider to Vagrant
ii  virtualbox                                    6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1              amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
ii  virtualbox-dkms                               6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1              amd64        x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
ii  virtualbox-qt                                 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1              amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
```

Extension Pack installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to do a classic install, then try to connect stuff all together (Vagrant <-> VirtualBox).

A link that helped: [Make a Hackintosh in a Virtualbox](https://web.archive.org/web/20221030121034/https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Hackintosh-in-a-Virtualbox).

And after creating the VM in VirtualBox, you need to pass this script.

```
#!/bin/sh

VBoxManage modifyvm "MacOsX" --cpuid-set 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff
VBoxManage setextradata "MacOsX" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "iMac11,3"
VBoxManage setextradata "MacOsX" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion" "1.0"
VBoxManage setextradata "MacOsX" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct" "Iloveapple"
VBoxManage setextradata "MacOsX" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey" "ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"
VBoxManage setextradata "MacOsX" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC" 1
VBoxManage modifyvm "MacOsX" --cpu-profile "Intel Core i7-6700K"
VBoxManage setextradata "MacOsX" VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode 4
```

The CPU line `"Intel Core i7-6700K"` was added, was not on [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/VirtualBox#Install_MacOS_guest).

Was stuck without this line with `LOG:EXITBS:START` in `TTY`.

Then, you can start the VM. Enjoy!

**Edit**:

One way to run it in headless mode:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'kill $pid; rm -f /tmp/vmMacOsX.$$' 0 1 2 3 15

VBoxHeadless --startvm "MacOsX" &>/tmp/vmMacOsX.$$ &
pid=$!

until grep -q '100%' /tmp/vmMacOsX.$$; do
    sleep 1
done

ssh -t vagrant@192.168.0.123
```